# C# WebBrowser object not loading Uri

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, webbrowser-control

I believe that I've researched here and elsewhere enough to justify posting this as a new question.  My situation is similar but not identical to others' reported problems.

As a proof of concept I am building an app that hits the Google StreetView and StaticMaps API's and displays images of them in a C# Windows Form (.net 3.5 for the time being).  The form has the WebBrowser object, four TextBoxes (Street, City, State, Zip) for address input and a "Go" button.

Here's my code (and from other reputable posts/sites, this should be all I need):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GoogleMapsTest
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      webStreetView = new WebBrowser();
      Uri urlString = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x300&location=" +
         txtStreet.Text.Replace(" ", "+") + "+" +
         txtCity.Text.Replace(" ", "+") + "+" +
         txtState.Text.Replace(" ", "+") + "+" +
         txtZip.Text.Replace(" ", "+"));
      webStreetView.Navigate(urlString);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the form looks like it's going through the motions when the "GO" button is clicked (I can see the hourglass for an instant) but the WebBrowser object remains blank.

Here is what I have done to try to test:

1. Plugged a test URL into the URL property of the object in design
   mode - form loads with the image
2. Pulled the URI address out of the
   app in debug and tested it in my browser - works fine
3. Per advice found for similar problems, I tried adding in a call to
   WebBrowser.Refresh() - no dice
4. Please note that the line "webStreetView = new WebBrowser();" was put in as a troubleshooting attempt per my other comment.

It's probably something really simple that I'm overlooking.  If anyone can help point me in the right direction and find what I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a real url (*urlString*) which you think should work?

Comment: Yeah, like I said I can set the URL beforehand in design mode and that totally works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Apparently the default margins (7,7,7,7) for the WebBrowser object are the bare minimum (I had set them to zero in an attempt to just show a clean image with no border).

For those who attempted to answer this question for me in earnest, I thank you kindly.

For the person who downvoted my question: go fish.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new instance of the web browser.  Remove`webStreetView = new WebBrowser();` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should have mentioned that the code you're talking about was another debug attempt; it does not work without that either